# Скрытие элемента так чтобы браузер не загружал его на страницу

Tags: html, css

Нужно на маленьких экранах убрать тяжелые элементы которые на сайте появляются на больших экранах, но не просто скрыть, а сделать так чтобы браузер их не загружал и подгружал только на большом экране.
Ведь если использовать display:none; то браузер все равно загрузит элемент, но просто его не отобразит.

Comment: в чем проблема?

Comment: Нужно сделать так чтобы браузер загружал элемент только на определенном допустим на меленьком экране, а на других не загружал

Comment: Не просто не показывал, а именно не подгружал

Comment: зависит от разметки, вариантов может быть много, от отдельной версии для маленького разрешения, до подгрузки по ajax, по предоставленному описанию сложно сказать, что именно больше подойдет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сами себе придумали проблему, которой нет.

> `Display: none` Временно удаляет элемент из документа. Занимаемое им место не резервируется и веб-страница формируется так, словно элемента и не было.

Добавление блока через `javascript`

```js
var third = document.createElement('div'); // создание нового элемента
third.className = "third"; // присвоение ему класса
third.innerHTML = "<span>third</span>"; // наполнение его потомками

window.onresize = function() { // отслеживание изменения размеров окна
  if (!(document.querySelector('.third')) && window.innerWidth < 500) {
    // проверка на существование блока и на размер окна меньше 500 пикселей
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(third); // добавление чайлда
  } else if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
    // альтернативная провека на размер окна больше 500 пикселей
    document.getElementById('main').removeChild(third); // удаление чайлда
  }
}
```

```css
.first {background: red;}
.second {background: green;}
.third {background: blue;}
#main {color: white; font-size: 24px;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="first"><span>first</span></div>
  <div class="second"><span>second</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Полностью согласен, проблема просто не в том чтобы скрыть элемент, а в том чтобы его браузер не подгружал, чтобы снизить время подгрузки сайта.
А при использовании display:none; он да скрывается все хорошо, но в самом начале когда браузер загружает страницу он же загружает также и контент которому присвоено свойство display:none; но просто его не отображает, если я не прав в понимании display:none; просьба поправить.

Comment: Можете использовать JS, чтобы добавлять элемент на нужных разрешениях, например.

Comment: А можете скинуть пример на js, я в нем плох просто, но по примеру постораюсь разобраться

Comment: Обновил решение: вынес переменные за пределы `if` для правильной видимости извне, добавил удаление чайлда в пример